# How to get case information?

Tags: rest-api, integration

I am beginner to SFDC programming and wanted to get some information about whether that case exists or not. something like that.
I am connecting my .NET application to SFDC and trying to get case information.

How can I achieve that? any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This is quite a broad question. Did you do some research of your own?

There's an extensive example here https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Integrating_Force.com_with_Microsoft_.NET

Just replace the query:

```
"select FirstName, LastName, Phone from Lead where email = 'john.smith@salesforce.com'"
```

by a query on Case, e.g.:

```
"select Id, Subject, CreatedDate  from Case where subject = 'a new case'"
```

The fields you can query on the Case object on your particular SF instance should be visible from your WSDL.

Then later on in the code, assign the query result to a Case object:
replace:

```
Lead lead = (Lead)queryResult.records[i];
```

by something like:

```
Case theCase = (Case)queryResult.records[i];
```